# Unable to connect to Asp.net API after adding middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using service fabric to build asp.net APIs and it works fine. As soon I add this line in startup.cs, I get connection refused error.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<GlobalRequestHandler>();

       }
```

I noticed that GlobalRequestHandler constructor is not getting called and my startup.cs Configure functions goes on an infinite loop. GlobalRequestHandler contructor has parameters(3) and 2 parameters are injected fine, 3rd parameter is causing Dependency injection issue.

**Error: connect ECONNREFUSED**

Comment: Does GlobalRequestHandler constructor have parameters? Actually you had better post the code of GlobalRequestHandler

Comment: @feihoa there are 3 parameters, 2 parameters are injected fine, 3rd parameter is causing DI issue. Not sure how to fix this.